# R package RISmed: Different results using the EUtilsget or summary function

Tags: r, pubmed

I obtain different results using the EUtilsSummary or EUtilsGet function of the RISmed R-package to query paper listed in pubmed. In both functions the same query was used.

```
library(RISmed)
topic <- "Valproic+acid|Valproate[Title/Abstract]+ALDH5A1[Title/Abstract]"
r <- EUtilsSummary(topic, db= "pubmed")  
QueryCount(r)
```

As you see three papers were counted in pubmed using the summary function. But the "Get function" will only find two:

```
EUtilsGet(r, db= "pubmed")
EUtilsGet(QueryId(r))
```

Do you have any ideas or explanations of this behavior? The [third paper (PubmedID: 20301374)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=20301374%5Buid%5D) will discarded although it is regularly listed in the database.

Answer (score -2):

I have indeed the same problem. I get 124 575 results with the EUtilsSummary while just searching on NCBI I get 125 661 results. Is the database where EUtilsSummary takes its information maybe not updated regularly?

You find that with entrezsearch you get the same problem and alternatives are given:
[Different result on browser search vs Bio.entrez search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455495/different-result-on-browser-search-vs-bio-entrez-search)

[Entrez E-Search results not matching up with online results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671876/entrez-e-search-results-not-matching-up-with-online-results)

In the meantime, I contacted NCBI about this and they send me this answer:

> The E-utilities API is retrieving data from the legacy PubMed database. The new PubMed is built with updated technology. Since they are two separate systems, counts will not always match up. Indexing is done at different times for each system, so additions, deletions (e.g., removing duplicates), or updates to records aren't taking effect at the same time in both places. Additionally, there are some changes in search syntax and search translations for the new PubMed that may affect the number of search results. For example, Automatic Term Mapping has been augmented to include additional British and American spellings, singular and plural word forms, and other synonyms to provide more consistent and comprehensive search retrieval. To see how PubMed translated your query, see the search details included in History and Search Details on the Advanced Search page. Using this translated query in your E-Utilities search can help bring the E-Utilities results closer to the website results; however, the different update schedules mean that results may still be slightly different. Later this year, NCBI will be moving to an updated version of the E-utilities API for PubMed using the same technology as the PubMed web interface. This update will keep E-utilities in sync with the web interface.

It should thus be solved at the end of this year.