# Entrez E-Search results not matching up with online results

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython

I am using the code below to perform an *esearch*, but the IDs that I get from *IdList* are not matching up with the IDs on the online search.

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "myEmail@gmail.com"
handle = Entrez.esearch(db = "nucleotide", term = "chordata[orgn] AND 
chromosome", retmax = 10, idtype = "acc")
genome_ids = Entrez.read(handle)['IdList']
print(genome_ids)
```

When I print the id's out they don't match up with the ones online.Does anyone know why? These are the id's I get when I print out genome_ids:

```
['NG_017163.2', 'NM_017553.3', 'NG_059281.1', 'NM_005101.4', 
'MH423692.1', 'MH423691.1', 'MH423690.1', 'MH423689.1', 'MH423688.1', 
'MH423687.1']
```

Here is the link to the online search: 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=chordata%5Borgn%5D+AND+chromosome

Also does anyone know how I can download the chromosomal and mitochondrial genome of all the organisms from the chordata phylum.I want to do it using BioPython through the E-utilities.

Comment: Show a link to your exact online search with the resulting ids and show say the first 10 `genome_ids` that are printed, which ids are the correct ones? Maybe you're querying the wrong database?

Comment: BTW downloading all chordate genomes will be an enormous data-set (all sequenced animals plus more), think carefully before you try that!

Comment: I have added the ids and the search link to the post. Is there a way to download maybe like 1000 chordata genomes (for 1000 organisms?)

Answer (score 0):

> How I can download the chromosomal and mitochondrial genome of all the organisms from the chordata phylum

1. Go to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi
2. Enter `chordata` in the 'search for' box, select `complete name` in the dropdown list
3. Enter a high number for the levels (e.g. `30`), and select the filter `has genome sequence` in the dropdown list
4. Check the `nucleotide` checkbox

You will now view a full taxonomic tree of the chordata with its subtaxa. The number behind each taxid is the number of sequences for that taxid. So, NCBI contains 84,366,537 different sequences of chordata.

You probably don't have enough space to download them all, so make a selection, click on the number behind the taxid, and choose `Send to` >  `File` > `FASTA`.