# Different result on browser search vs Bio.entrez search

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, pubmed

I am getting different result when I use Bio Entrez to search. For example when I search on browser using query "covid side effect" I get 344 result where as I get only 92 when I use Bio Entrez. This is the code I was using.

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "Your.Name.Here@example.org"
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", retmax=40, term="covid side effect", idtype="acc")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()
print(record['Count'])
```

I was hoping if someone could help me with this discrepancy.

Comment: Oddly, it looks like 93 here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/search/all/?term=%22covid+side+effect%22 under PubMed (matching Biopython), but then it's >350 when you click through https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=%22covid%20side%20effect%22&sort=date

Comment: @Chris_Rands Exactly, this is really weird. It seems to be a well known issue. I couldn't find the solution for this issue at all. Number could have increased because there could have been new publication  :D

Comment: @Chris_Rands, I found a work around to get this issue fixed but  I think there is definitely something wrong with pubmed API not returning same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason everyone seemed to have same issue whether it's R api or Python API. I have found a work around to get the same result. It is slow but it gets job done. If your result is less than 10k you could probably use Selenium to get the pubmedid.  Else, we can scrape the data using code below. I hope this will help someone in future.

```
import requests
# # Custom Date Range
# req = requests.get("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=covid&filter=dates.2009/01/01-2020/03/01&format=pmid&sort=pubdate&size=200&page={}".format(i))

# # Custom Year Range
# req = requests.get("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=covid&filter=years.2010-2019&format=pmid&sort=pubdate&size=200&page={}".format(i))


# #Relative Date 
# req = requests.get("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=covid&filter=datesearch.y_1&format=pmid&sort=pubdate&size=200&page={}".format(i))

# # filter language 
# # &filter=lang.english

# # filter human 
# #&filter=hum_ani.humans

# Systematic Review
#&filter=pubt.systematicreview

# Case Reports 
# &filter=pubt.casereports

# Age
# &filter=age.newborn

search = "covid lungs"
# search_list = "+".join(search.split(' '))

def id_retriever(search_string):
    string = "+".join(search_string.split(' '))
    result = []
    old_result = len(result)
    for page in range(1,10000000):
        req = requests.get("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term={string}&format=pmid&sort=pubdate&size=200&page={page}".format(page=page,string=string))

        for j in req.iter_lines():
            decoded = j.decode("utf-8").strip(" ")
            length = len(decoded)
            if "log_displayeduids" in decoded and length > 46:
                data = (str(j).split('"')[-2].split(","))
                result = result + data
                data = []
        new_result = len(result)
        if new_result != old_result:
            old_result = new_result
        else:
            break
    return result

ids=id_retriever(search)
len(ids)
```